# its about triggers

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

prevent the overlap of dates. we have 2 dates i.e. start date and end_date 
we need to write a trigger that prevents the overlap of the dates.
i.e. we can't have a new entry if the start date of what we are entering is already there.
we should consider both situations i.e. new_boking_from > the old_booking_from and new_booking_to < old_booking_to . Please help me with this.

CODE FOR THE SAME IS :

```
set echo on ;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_booking

BEFORE INSERT ON booking

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

if (((:new.resort_id,:new.cabin_no)in (select  b.resort_id ,b.cabin_no  from booking b)) 
and 
(:new.booking_from) > (select b.booking from booking where :new.resort_id = b.resort_id and :new.guest_no = b.guest_no)) 
or 
(((:new.resort_id,:new.cabin_no)in (select  b.resort_id ,b.cabin_no  from booking b))
and 
(:new.booking_to)< (select b.booking from booking where :new.resort_id = b.resort_id and :new.guest_no = b.guest_no))

then 

raise_application_error(-20000, 'This is an overlap');

end if;

end;
/

set echo off;
```

Comment: I invested some of my time yesterday answering your previous question on triggers. You subsequently deleted that question without any explanation. Maybe you had a good reason for doing so but you'll forgive me if I don't feel like investing any more of my time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are going to run into is a mutating table exception.  You can't query the table that you are currently updating (Don't use the autonomous transaction pragma, it isn't necessary here).  Depending on your version, you can create a compound trigger.  There are a number of resources which will walk you through the overall process.
Here is one to get you started: [blog post](http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2016/12/get-rid-of-mutating-table-trigger.html).